# ClassCastException after obfuscation internal classes with suspend functions

Tags: kotlin, proguard, classcastexception, suspend, android-r8

I'm building a kotlin AAR library which I need to obfuscate before publishing. I have the following structure:

```
package com.example.token

interface TokenManager {
    suspend fun getTokenStatus(): String
}
```

The above is a public interface available for the api client. The implementation is moved to an internal package:

```
package com.example.token.internal
    
internal class RestApiTokenManager: TokenManager {
    override suspend fun getTokenStatus(): String {
    //....
    }
}
```

My obfuscation exception includes only the public interface package:

```
-keep class com.example.token.*{*;}
```

Unfortunately this results in a class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: e.e.a.a.l.d.e$a cannot be cast to c.a.a.e.a.a$a
```

In order to fix this I need to add an obfuscation exception for the implementation package, which I want to avoid.

Now the true weird problem is that the `ClassCastException` disappears as soon as I remove the `suspend` modifier.

I tried adding `-keeptkotlinmetadata` but I get  `R8: Unknown option` error.

I've been stuck with this for a long time now, without a solution which won't force me to add an exception for my internal implementation classes.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug in R8, and I have opened [issue 167373399](http://issuetracker.google.com/167373399) to track this.

Please follow up there with information on the version of Android Studio / R8 you are currently using?

Please also take a look at [this Medium post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/shrinking-kotlin-libraries-and-applications-using-kotlin-reflection-with-r8-6fe0a0e2d115), which has more details on shrinking Kotlin code with R8.

Comment: thank you, I was actually about to create the ticket tomorrow. Do you know how to print the r8 version? I'm simply have `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1` which I guess defines the R8 version used?

Answer (score 0):

The discussion continued and was concluded on the issuetracker [167373399](http://issuetracker.google.com/167373399)